# Multiply specific weights to columns and add together in new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have three columns of data and want to multiply different scalar values to each and then sum them into a column. Let's suppose I want to multiply Attibute_1 by 10, Attribute_2 by 5, and Attribute_3 by 2

```
Attribute_1   |   Attribute_2   |   Attribute_3   |    Score    |
_________________________________________________________________
      10              10                15              180
       5               5                10               95
```

Is there an elegant solution that is similar to a "sumproduct" kind of functionality?

E.g.

```
cols = [df['Attribute_1'], df['Attribute_2'], df['Attribute_3']]
weights = [10, 5, 2]
df['Score'] = cols * weights
```

I do not want the following solution because I am looking for something more elegant if I have many columns and many weights.

```
df['Score'] = df['Attribute_1'] * 10 + df['Attribute_2'] * 5 + df['Attribute_3'] * 2
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `mul` method:

```
attributes = ["Attribute_1", "Attribute_2", "Attribute_3"]
weights = [10, 5, 2]

df['Score'] = df[attributes].mul(weights).sum(1)
df

# Attribute_1   Attribute_2   Attribute_3   Score
#0         10            10            15     180
#1          5             5            10      95
```