# Treating NaN as zero in arithmetic operations?

Tags: python, pandas, nan

Here's a simple example of the sort of thing I'm wrestling with:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: import numpy as np
In [3]: test = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,4),columns=list('ABCD'))
In [4]: for i in range(4):
  ....:    test.iloc[i,i] = np.nan

In [5]: test
Out[5]:
           A         B         C         D
0        NaN  0.136841 -0.854138 -1.890888
1  -1.261724       NaN  0.875647  1.312823
2   1.130999 -0.208402       NaN  0.256644
3  -0.158458 -0.305250  0.902756       NaN
```

Now, if I use `sum` to sum the rows, all the `NaN` values are treated as zeros:

```
In [6]: test['Sum'] = test.loc[:,'A':'D'].sum(axis=1)

In [7]: test
Out[7]: 
          A         B         C         D       Sum
0       NaN  0.136841 -0.854138 -1.890888 -2.608185
1 -1.261724       NaN  0.875647  1.312823  0.926745
2  1.130999 -0.208402       NaN  0.256644  1.179241
3 -0.158458 -0.305250  0.902756       NaN  0.439048
```

But in my case, I may need to do a bit of work on the values first; for example scaling them:

```
In [8]: test['Sum2'] = test.A + test.B/2 - test.C/3 + test.D

In [9]: test
Out[9]: 
          A         B         C         D       Sum  Sum2
0       NaN  0.136841 -0.854138 -1.890888 -2.608185   NaN
1 -1.261724       NaN  0.875647  1.312823  0.926745   NaN
2  1.130999 -0.208402       NaN  0.256644  1.179241   NaN
3 -0.158458 -0.305250  0.902756       NaN  0.439048   NaN
```

As you see, the `NaN` values carry across into the arithmetic to produce `NaN` output, which is what you'd expect.

Now, I don't want to replace all `NaN` values in my dataframe with zeros: it is helpful to me to distinguish between zero and `NaN`.  I could replace `NaN` with something else: I'm dealing with large volumes of student grades, and i need to distinguish between a grade of zero, and a `NaN` which at the moment I'm using to indicate that the particular assessment task was not attempted.  (It takes the place of what would be a blank cell in a traditional spreadsheet.)  But whatever I replace the `NaN` values with, it needs to be something that can be treated as zero in the operations I may perform.  What are my options here?

Answer (score 7):

Use the fillna function

```
test['Sum2'] = test.A.fillna(0) + test.B.fillna(0)/2 - test.C.fillna(0)/3 + test.D.fillna(0)
```

Comment: There is an error: you should write  `test.B.fillna(0)/2` instead of
 `test.B/2.fillna(0)`

Comment: Sorry, typo.. Modifying immediately.

Answer (score 2):

If the dataframe is not huge you can try:

```
test["Sum"] = test.sum(axis=1)
test2 = test.fillna(0)
test["Sum2"] = test2.A + test2.B/2 - test2.C/3 + test2.D
del test2
```

It will be interesting to know if there is a way to do the second sum in one line only.

**Update**

if you have `1e5` rows or less the method I suggested is slightly faster than the one suggested by kmcodes, then things changes.

```
n = int(1e5)
test = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(n,4),columns=list('ABCD'))
for i in range(4):
    test.iloc[i,i] = np.nan

%%timeit
test2 = test.fillna(0)
test["Sum2"] = test2.A + test2.B/2 - test2.C/3 + test2.D
del test2
3.95 ms ± 51.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit
test['Sum2'] = test.A.fillna(0) + test.B.fillna(0)/2 - test.C.fillna(0)/3 + test.D.fillna(0)
4.12 ms ± 16.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

**Update 2**

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42675987/4819376)

In your case you can just

```
weights = [1, 1/2, -1/3, 1]
test["Sum2"] = test.fillna(0).mul(weights).sum(axis=1)
```

keep in mind that this seems to be consistently slower than the other two.

Comment: Thank you - this is a neat method: first creating a new dataframe in which all NaNs are turned into zeros, and use the results of this new dataframe to compute a new column in the original one.  Simple and effective.

Answer (score 0):

You can also concat and find the sum to get the features offered by `sum()` i.e

```
test['Sum2'] = pd.concat([test.A,test.B/2, test.C/(-3),test.D],1).sum(1)

       A         B         C         D      Sum2
0       NaN  0.181923 -0.526074  1.084549  1.350869
1  0.999836       NaN -0.862583 -0.473933  0.813431
2  1.043463  0.252743       NaN -0.863199  0.306635
3 -0.047286  1.432500  0.100041       NaN  0.635616
```